# How do I determine what packages are dependent on a given package in R?

Tags: r

I have a package in my library and I do not know where it came from. Presumably it was downloaded as a dependency of another package I use. How can I find out which package(s) are dependent on a package of interest?

Comment: If it's a CRAN package, go there, as each package's page has both a "depends' and a "reverse depends" list provided.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, where is the reverse depends? I do not see it in either the summary HTML or the reference manual?

Comment: Go to the "packages" page and click on any package. That brings up a variant of the summary page, and there'll be info listed near the top for what it depends on and near the bottom for reverse depends. For example, the `bvpSolve` page lists "Depends: R (≥ 2.01), rootSolve, deSolve"  and "Reverse depends: diffEq"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `installed.packages` which gives the list of all your installed packages with their dependencies (as a matrix object). Say for instance that you want to find which packages are dependent on `rJava`:

```
#get my installed packages
x<-installed.packages()
#find packages dependent on rJava
x[grepl("rJava",x[,"Depends"]),"Package"]
#the result for my R installation
#  XLConnect        xlsx    xlsxjars 
#"XLConnect"      "xlsx"  "xlsxjars"
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to find packages dependent on rJava, just use tools package.

```
library(tools)
dependsOnPkgs("rJava")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the tidyverse way:

```
library(tidyverse) 
packages <- installed.packages()
required_package <- "rJava"
as_tibble(packages) %>%    
    filter(str_detect(Depends, required_package) | 
           str_detect(Imports, required_package) | 
           str_detect(LinkingTo, required_package)) %>%
    pull(Package)
```